# What is the equivalent R function to GAMMA.INV(probability,alpha,beta) Excel function?

Tags: r, statistics, gamma-distribution

I need to find the inverse of the gamma cumulative distribution. I know there is `GAMMA.INV(probability,alpha,beta)` function just to do that in excel. How can I achieve this in R language?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In R, for most probability distributions, 
there are four functions, called d, p, q, r, 
(e.g., `dnorm`, `pnorm`, `qnorm`, `rnorm`)
giving you the density (d), cumulative distribution function (p, since the result is a probability), its inverse (q, since the result is a quantile), and r to sample from the distribution.

For the Gamma distribution, the inverse of the cumulative distribution function is therefore `qgamma`.

Comment: Is same equivalent available in .Net? What is the best library which have this function?